# Java ArrayList for integers

Tags: java, arrays

I have values that I'd like to add into an ArrayList to keep track of what numbers have shown up.
The values are integers so I created an ArrayList;

```
ArrayList<Integer[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
int x = 5
list.add(x);
```

But I'm unable to add anything to the ArrayList using this method.
It works if I use Strings for the array list. Would I have to make it a String array and then somehow convert the array to integers?

EDIT: I have another question. I'd like the list to only hold 3 values. How would I do so?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

List of `Integer`.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
int x = 5;
list.add(x);
```

Comment: array is static in nature where as ArrayList is dynamic growable list backed by array.

Answer (score 7):

You are trying to add an integer into an `ArrayList` that takes an array of integers `Integer[]`. It should be

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

or better

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: When you will guide OP (or somebody else) about programming to interfaces, please refer to [What does it mean to “program to an interface”?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/1065197).

Answer (score 3):

you are not creating an arraylist for integers, but you are trying to create an arraylist for arrays of integers.

so if you want your code to work just put.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
int x = 5;
list.add(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

you should not use `Integer[]` array inside the list as arraylist itself is a kind of array. Just leave the `[]` and it should work

Answer (score 1):

Actually what u did is also not wrong your declaration is right . With your declaration JVM will create a ArrayList of integer arrays i.e each entry in arraylist correspond to an integer array hence your add function should pass a integer array as a parameter.

For Ex:

```
list.add(new Integer[3]);
```

In this way first entry of ArrayList is an integer array which can hold at max 3 values.

Answer (score 1):

The `[]` makes no sense in the moment of making an ArrayList of Integers because I imagine you just want to add Integer values.
Just use

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

to create the ArrayList and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Here there are two different concepts that are merged togather in your question.

First : Add Integer array into List. Code is as follows.

```
List<Integer[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
Integer[] intArray1 = new Integer[] {2, 4};
Integer[] intArray2 = new Integer[] {2, 5};
Integer[] intArray3 = new Integer[] {3, 3};
Collections.addAll(list, intArray1, intArray2, intArray3);
```

Second : Add integer value in list.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
int x = 5
list.add(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about creating an *ArrayList of a set amount of Integers*?

The **below method** returns an ArrayList of a set amount of Integers.

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> createRandomList(int sizeParameter)
{
    // An ArrayList that method returns
    ArrayList<Integer> setIntegerList = new ArrayList<Integer>(sizeParameter);
    // Random Object helper
    Random randomHelper = new Random();
    
    for (int x = 0; x < sizeParameter; x++)
    {
        setIntegerList.add(randomHelper.nextInt());
    }   // End of the for loop
    
    return setIntegerList;
}
```