# Java ArrayList of Integer[], how to access elements

Tags: java

I am using an ArrayList of  to create lists.
For example:

```
Index 0: 1 3
Index 1: 4 5
Index 2: 1 3 7
```

How can I access the second element of the first index of the ArrayList? Couldn't find the answer on Google, so I asked here.

Comment: Why not just use a 2d array?

Comment: I googled "ArrayList of integers" and the first result was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14421943/java-arraylist-for-integers

Comment: Can't find on google ??

Comment: Show us some code, because a `ArrayList` isn't an array of `Integer`(s).

Comment: I mean if its a true Arraylist. You could use  `myList.get(0)` which would return the first index, but past that I don't know :P

Comment: I found the correct answer on @Fev, I don't use a 2d Array because it's harder to add elements dinamically. ArrayList of integer[] it's much easier.

Comment: @PavelMarian Sounds like you should be using a `List<List<Integer>> al = new ArrayList<>();` why use one dynamic collection and a fixed width object?

Comment: @HanletEscaño That looks like an accident.  This is about an "ArrayList of arrays of integers", not "ArrayList of integers".  But the second phrase happened to work because someone put the wrong title on their question.  My point is: don't assume that everyone should just be able to find things with Google.  It's not always easy to guess what search terms to put in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
yourList.get(0)[1]; // that's it !!
```

If you want to iterate over it :

```
for (Integer[] outer : yourList) {
  for(Integer inner : outer) {
    System.out.println(inner);
  }
}
```

Comment: If it was so simple why I couldn't find it over the internet, thanks a lot.Gonna try it ! Mark answer after time pass.

Answer (score 2):

By your question, I am guessing you have something like this?

```
List<Integer[]> list = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
Integer[] a1 = {1,3};
Integer[] a2 = {4,5};
Integer[] a3 = {1,3,7};

list.add(a1);
list.add(a2);
list.add(a3);
```

Then all you need to do is simply call:

```
Integer result = list.get(0)[1];
```

The `get(0)` pulls the first `Integer[]` out of the list, then to get the second element, you use `[1]`

Answer (score 0):

where do you see the exception? have you tried this?

```
    List<Integer[]> list = new ArrayList<Integer[]>(3);
    Integer[] a1 = {1,3};
    Integer[] a2 = {4,5};
    Integer[] a3 = {1,3,7};

    list.add(a1);
    list.add(a2);
    list.add(a3);

    Integer result = list.get(0)[1];
```

There aren't any exception. The arraylist have three elementes because you have three elemente (a1,a2,a3),

Answer (score -1):

You have `List<Integer[]> l = new ArrayList<Integer[]>(3);`

if you want the second element of the first index:

```
l.get(0)[1].
```

Comment: Your declaration of the `List` won't even compile. Did you mean to put something else?

Comment: I forgot >, List<Integer[]> l = new ArrayList<Integer[]>(3); and afer that, you have to fill the list.

Comment: Your code will also throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: if you want the second element, you need a for. My answer was a example. for (int i=0;i<3; i++)