# JAVA: Asking for two ints in an ArrayList

Tags: java

I want to add a trail to a player on a grid, similar to that of the game "Snake." However, when I go to make an array list, I get an error. Here is the code for creating it.

```
ArrayList<Integer, Integer> trail = new ArrayList<Integer, Integer>();
```

I get the error "Incorrect number of arguments."

How am I supposed to make this to keep track of which coordinates have been gone over by the player?

Answer (score 4):

Make a class Pair which will look like something like this:

```
class Pair {
    public int x, y;
}
```

or you can use predefined java.awt.Point class. Then in your code use

```
ArrayList<Pair>
```

instead of

```
ArrayList<Integer, Integer>.
```

Answer (score 1):

Array list only takes one arguement.
You can refer to this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14421943/java-arraylist-for-integers).

Solution  to your problem is you can use hash map or double dimension array as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList` takes only one argument, like this:

```
 ArrayList<Integer> trail = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

If you need to store a key and a value, use `HashMap`

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> trail = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also make a Arraylist of integer array like
                     new Arraylist;